# Any way to 'hack' a IBD file into mysql without using IMPORT TABLESPACE ? (Mysql 8.0.19 tends to segfault during import)

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0

Due to NDA I've difficulties providing an actual sample, that also makes filing a bug report quite useless.
It is a completely normal table, no specialities and 7 simple indexes on 1-2 columns each.

The Problem I have is that I have to regularly transfer a table between two Mysql 8.0.19 Servers (latest Percona stable they provide for Docker) and mysql crashes on signal 11 (segfault) every single time.
I've done this the same for a year without the issue and the table barely changed, crashing started recently.

I have this issue on 4 servers, 3 of them using Docker, one 1 normal Debian APT package

**What I have tried:**
1) I rebuilt the entire table to ensure the IBD file has no internal corruption.
2) I tried to split the table into multiple parts, in these cases the segfault crash only happens one part. Though I do not have the time to further reduce it to a single row.

```
06:55:37 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7fee7cde6100
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7ff03c0f4d80 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x2e) [0x559950e1380e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x351) [0x55994ff2e641]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x110e0) [0x7ff04770e0e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(lob::z_index_page_t::get_n_index_entries() const+0x8) [0x5599512a10f8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(lob::z_index_page_t::import(unsigned long)+0x18) [0x5599512a1628]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(PageConverter::update_page(buf_block_t*, unsigned long&)+0x3e1) [0x559950ff8051]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(PageConverter::operator()(unsigned long, buf_block_t*)+0x322) [0x559950ff86a2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(fil_tablespace_iterate(dict_table_t*, unsigned long, PageCallback&)+0x9ef) [0x55995122027f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(row_import_for_mysql(dict_table_t*, dd::Table*, row_prebuilt_t*)+0xdc6) [0x559950ff9ad6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::discard_or_import_tablespace(bool, dd::Table*)+0x422) [0x559950ecf742]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_discard_import_tablespace::mysql_discard_or_import_tablespace(THD*, TABLE_LIST*)+0x1bc) [0x55994fe787cc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x2645) [0x55994fe07b15]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*)+0x360) [0x55994fe0ae70]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x1e93) [0x55994fe0d203]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x168) [0x55994fe0deb8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xfcc9c8) [0x55994ff1f9c8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x23fdeb5) [0x559951350eb5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x74a4) [0x7ff0477044a4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7ff04578fd0f]
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
```

**My main questions:**
1) 
Given that I have an exported IBD file (created as in manual with a flush and CFG file) and create the new table using 1:1 the same syntax as from "SHOW CREATE TABLE": Is there no way to access it like an MyIsam table ?

2) 
Given that MyIsam is heading to 'deprecated' I am reluctant using it for this purpose, it would probably be much easier using it.
Is there any idea for how long it will be available still ?

Like I said in the beginning I have limitations, I can't provide a reproduceable case and finding the row which causes this is too time demanding.

**Update**
Uncompressing the table solved the segmentation faults, I hope it won't happen with the larger tables.
In this case I just list 30GB storage, that was an acceptable solution.

In case a Mysql developer reads this: the compression of blobs seems to have a serious bug somewhere.

Comment: As its repeatable, won't a table of the same structure with different table/column/index names be sufficient to fall outside the NDA. Use this with artificial data to reproduce this.

Comment: I could modify it but the problem is data row related, it's one (or more) rows that cause this so the structure wouldn't help much. (just a couple varchars, integers, dates and a few enums) And finding the row that causes the crash is beyond my available time. Already wasted 2 weeks just getting to this point:(

Comment: The crash is in the compressed LOB part of the code. Maybe try to make it not compressed. [ref -MySQL 8.0: New Storage Format for Compressed BLOBs](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-new-storage-format-for-compressed-blobs/)

Comment: @danblack Hmm it might be related. I do have a mediumblob.  
I will try the table uncompressed, it's just 80GB so the additional space should be manageable!  
Good suggestion, thanks  

P.S. Thanks a lot for spotting the "LOB" thing, I didn't know it stands for "large object"  and thought it's solely index related.

Answer (score 1):

In a word - no.

InnoDB pages contain a header, and the node ID is encoded in each page header. If this doesn't match what is in the master tablespace, created when the node was initialized, it won't work. `IMPORT TABLESPACE` rewrites the headers of each page in the imported tablespace.

What you're asking for simply isn't possible with InnoDB.

Comment: I guessed so, though it's a real huge downside of the format that seems to designated to be the one and only since 2020.
Do you have an idea if MyISAM will stay available in releases during the next 5 years ?

Comment: I suspect based on [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/11/mysql-8-0-end-myisam/) that it won't be removed from 8.0 but the next major release will remove it. Note it also says the hot copy import isn't there. MariaDB definitely will keep it because Monty loves it.